# Gnuplot - pdf filesize increases when removing tilt

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, filesize, rasterize

When I plot a densityplot using something like

```
plot 'xyz.dat' w image u 1:2:3
```

the filesize is nice and small how it should be.
However if I remove an experimental tilt with

```
plot 'xyz.dat' w image u 1:($2+tilt*$1):3
```

the figure is not rendered anymore and plot as a vectorial graphics, resulting in a filesize of some Megabyte. This happens with pdf and pdfcairo terminal (eps is even larger).
Anyway to force gnuplot into rasterizing only the plot and not the axes etc?
And is this a bug since I didn't change any other options (btw: still v4.6)?

Thanks alot!

Comment: There is not much you can do in gnuplot: an image is plotted as raster image only if the domain is rectangular, and not a parallelogram like you have when you add the tilt.So you could plot only the tilted data to a png file and then plot that png into the PDF. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131106/33933